# What is the proper way to include the zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, set-include-path

I have downloaded the Zend Framework and put it just above the server root (Where `/tmp` is and such) and I'm having trouble getting it recognized by a single PHP file. I am using a shared host and this is how I am including the directory:

```
set_include_path('/home/content/xx/xxxxxxx/zend/library');
require_once('Zend/loader.php');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
```

Comment: I suggest to start with http://zendframework.com/manual/en/manual.html

Comment: I'm guessing the actual problem is `Warning: require_once(Zend/loader.php) [function.require-once]:
failed to open stream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is a case sensitivity one. The `Zend_Loader` class' filename is `Loader.php` (capital "L").

Try

```
set_include_path('/home/content/xx/xxxxxxx/zend/library');
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
```